# representing integers as linear combination of integers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

Let $a,b,a',b'$ be $r-\epsilon_1$ bit positive integers.

Let $c,d$ be $s+\epsilon_2$ bit positive integers.

Fix a pair $c,d$ and vary $a,b$ over all $r-\epsilon_1$ bit numbers. Do we have almost $2^{2r-2\epsilon_1}$ different $r+s+\delta$ bit integers each of form $ac+bd$ or $a'c+b'd$ for some fixed $\delta$?

Does this mean we have almost $2^{4r-4\epsilon_1}$ different $r+2s+\delta$ bit integers of form $c(ac+bd)+d(a'c+b'd)$ for some fixed $\delta$?

If we vary $c,d$ over $2^t$ different random pairs, do we have $2^{t+4r-4\epsilon_1}$ different integers of form $c(ac+bd)+d(a'c+b'd)$ for some fixed $\delta$?

Comment: You have $a\ge m$, $b\ge m$, $c\ge n$, $d\ge n$, so $ac+bd\ge2mn$.

Comment: ic good point. let me change. The main point is whether I can represent all numbers between $mn$ and $4mn$. Is this possible the way I am portraying?

Comment: Do you still insist on $n\gt m$? If $m=n=2$, I don't think you can get 9.

Comment: changed the question to be more precise.